# Using dropdown to fill a field instead of listening

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors, html-select

I have had some help from here and a few places to build out a wonderful email signature generator. Currently any filled in info goes into the live preview. What I am trying to do now is fill out the live preview via dropdown.

In this example I am trying to allow a user to choose "fax" or "mobile" for a phone type. The goal being that it simply fills in the "f:" or "m:" in the live preview. I broke the code down just to this key element so you can see. The dropdown is the only thing I am trying to solve.

Hoping someone can guide me to where to at least look for a solution. I have experimented quite a bit with no luck.

```js
// We wrap our segment in an anonymous wrapper function to mitigate potential conflicts with any potential third party stuff.
(function() {

  // Loading animation
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.loading-screen').style.display = 'none';
    }, 1000);
  }

  // Adding the error validation
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input,select'),
    submitBtn = document.getElementById('generateButton'),
    signatureForm = document.getElementById('signatureForm'),
    mobileselectPhoneInput = document.getElementById('mobileselect_phone'),
    mobilePhoneInput = document.getElementById('mobile_phone'),
    mobileBlock = document.getElementById('mobile_phone_block'),
    faxPhoneInput = document.getElementById('fax_phone'),
    faxBlock = document.getElementById('fax_phone_block'),
    inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('[data-field]'),
    socialFields = document.querySelectorAll('[data-social]'),
    awardFields = document.querySelectorAll('[data-award]'),
    outputBox = document.getElementById('output-code-box'),
    previewBox = document.getElementById('signature-block'),
    getColumn = (id) => document.querySelector(`[data-column="${id}"]`);;

  for (let i = 0, x = inputs.length; i < x; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', function(ev) {
      if (!this.classList.contains('blurred')) {
        this.classList.add('blurred');
      }

      mobileBlock.style.display = mobilePhoneInput.value !== '' ? 'inline' : 'none';
      faxBlock.style.display = faxPhoneInput.value !== '' ? 'inline' : 'none';
      socialFields.forEach(social => {
        getColumn(social.id).style.display = social.value !== '' ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
      })
    }, false);
  }

  inputFields.forEach(field =>
    field.addEventListener('keyup', (ev) => {
      mobileBlock.style.display = ev.target.id === 'mobile_phone' || mobilePhoneInput.value !== '' ? 'inline' : 'none';
      getColumn(ev.target.id).innerText = ev.target.value;
      faxBlock.style.display = ev.target.id === 'fax_phone' || faxPhoneInput.value !== '' ? 'inline' : 'none';
      getColumn(ev.target.id).innerText = ev.target.value;

      switch (ev.target.id) {
        case 'email':
          getColumn(ev.target.id).href = `mailto:${ev.target.value}`;
          break;
        case 'office_address':
          getColumn(ev.target.id).href = `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=${ev.target.value}`;
          break;
        case 'web_address':
          getColumn(ev.target.id).href = `https://${ev.target.value}`;
          break;
        case 'office_phone':
          getColumn(ev.target.id).href = `tel:${ev.target.value}`;
          break;
        case 'mobile_phone':
          getColumn(ev.target.id).href = `tel:${ev.target.value}`;
          break;
        case 'fax_phone':
          getColumn(ev.target.id).href = `tel:${ev.target.value}`;
          break;
      }

    }, false)
  );

  handleForm = (ev) => {
    if (signatureForm.checkValidity()) {
      // minify the html to tidy up and present it for user.
      outputBox.value = previewBox.innerHTML.replace(/>\s+|\s+</g, function(m) {
        return m.trim();
      });
      document.getElementById('output-code').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      // Todo - do something less obnoxious to hold their hand and tell them something is wrong maybe disable the button until valid.
      alert('Missing required fields in the form.')
      console.log('Missing required fields, no soup for you.')
    }
  };

  copyCode = () => {
    outputBox.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
  }

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" dir="ltr">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <main role="main">
    <section class="expository" role="region" aria-label="expository">
      <section id="generator-container" role="group">
        <div style="background-color: #F2F2F2; padding: 20px; margin-right: 60px;">
          <h2>1. Enter as much of the below information as you can for your email signature.</h2>
          <form method="POST" action="." enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" role="form" id="signatureForm">
            <p id="formErrorContainer"></p>
            <span class="required-mark">Name</span>
            <label for="name">
        <input data-field type="text" id="name" name="name" title="Enter name" placeholder="e.g. John Doe" pattern="^([^0-9]*)$" autofocus required>
        <span>Enter valid name</span> <span class="success-validation-check"></span>
      </label>
            <span class="required-mark">Job Title</span>
            <label for="position">
        <input data-field type="text" id="position" name="position" title="Enter position" placeholder="e.g. Care Planner" pattern="^([^0-9]*)$" required>
        <span>Enter valid title</span> <span class="success-validation-check"></span>
      </label>
            <span role="presentation" class="required-mark">Office Phone Number</span>
            <br><br>
            <p style="text-align: left; color: #373737; font-size: 12px;"></p>
            <br>
            <label for="office_phone">
        <input data-field type="tel" id="office_phone" name="office_phone" title="Enter office phone number" placeholder="e.g. 1.855.983.4663">
        <span>Enter valid phone number</span> <span class="success-validation-check"></span>
      </label>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">Phone type</span>
            <label for="mobileselect_phone">
        <select data-field type="text" id="mobileselect_phone" name="mobileselect_phone" title="Mobile/fax">
            <option value="None" selected>None</option>
<option value="m:">mobile</option>
            <option value="f:">fax</option></select>
        <span>mobile or fax?</span> <span class="success-validation-check"></span>
      </label>
            <label for="mobile_phone">
        <input data-field type="tel" id="mobile_phone" name="mobile_phone" title="Enter phone number" placeholder="e.g. 555.123.4567">
        <span>Enter valid phone number</span> <span class="success-validation-check"></span>
      </label>


            <div id="generator-output">
              <h2>2. Live Signature Preview</h2>
              <br>

              <br>
              <hr style="height:0;border:0;border-bottom: #ddd 1px solid"><br>
              <aside id="generator-output-window">
                <figure id="signature-block">
                  <table width="525" style="width: 525px; color: #063852; font-size: 10pt;" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 200px;" align="center" valign=middle width="200">
                          <img width="200" height="79" border=0 src="assets/logo.gif"><br>
                          <br>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 325px; padding-left: 20px; border-left: #888a8d 1px solid" valign=top>
                          <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td height="25" style="font-size: 14pt; font-weight: 600; font-family: georgia; color: #063852" data-column="name"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="color: #063852; font-size: 10pt !important; font: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-weight: 600;" data-column="position">
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          <br>
                          <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <td>
                                  <a data-column="email" style="font-size: 10pt !important; font: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; text-decoration:none !important; color: #063852 !important;"></a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr height="23" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <td>
                                  <span style="font-size: 10pt !important; font-weight: 600;">t:</span>
                                  <a style="color: #063852 !important; font-size: 10pt !important; font: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; text-decoration:none !important;" data-column="office_phone"></a>

                                  <span id="mobile_phone_block" style="display: none">
                          | <span style="font-size: 10pt !important; font-weight: 600;" data-column="mobileselect_phone"></span>
                                  <a style="color: #063852 !important; font-size: 10pt !important; font: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; text-decoration:none !important;" data-column="mobile_phone"></a>
                                  </span>

                                  <span id="fax_phone_block" style="display: none">
                          <br><span style="font-size: 10pt !important; font-weight: 600;">f: </span>
                                  <a style="color: #063852 !important; font-size: 10pt !important; font: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; text-decoration:none !important;" data-column="fax_phone"></a>
                                  </span>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          <br>
                          <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
                                <td style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 10pt !important; font: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; color: #063852 !important;" data-column="office_name">
                                  <font size="2">
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr height="23" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <td>
                                  <a style="text-decoration:none !important; color: #063852 !important; font-size: 10pt !important; font: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';" data-column="office_address"></a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <td>
                                  <a style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #063852 !important; font-size: 10pt !important; font: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif';" data-column="web_address"></a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          <br>

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 20px">

                          <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td width="525" data-column="corporate" style="display:none; width: 525px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><img src="./assets/images/Awards_Corporate.gif" alt="Franchisees Choice 2020" width=525 style="width: 525px;"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr style="vertical-align: bottom;">


                        <td style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 0px;" colspan="2">

                          <p><span style="text-decoration:none !important; color: #063852 !important; font-size: 10pt; font: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; padding-bottom: 80px;" colspan="2" data-column="extra_legal"></span></p>
                          <br>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                </figure>
                <!-- <button type="button" onclick="handleForm()" style="width:100%;max-width:100%" id="generateButton">Generate Email Signature</button> -->

                <div id="output-code" style="margin-top: 2rem;display:none">
                  <label style="text-align:left">Copy and paste the code into your email signature:</label>
                  <button type="button" form="signatureForm" onclick="copyCode()" style="width:100%;max-width:100%">Copy The Code</button>
                  <textarea id="output-code-box" name="output-code" rows="8" style="width: 100%">
          </textarea>
                </div>
              </aside>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
    <!--/ End Main Form -->

  </main>

  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post the JavaScript. Also, there is no `<form>`  or `<select>`.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. The code above is all that is needed to run. You can see the script near the bottom. there is definitely a <form

The select is this section but it's all in the above code. 

        <select data-field type="text" id="mobileselect_phone" name="mobileselect_phone" title="Mobile/fax">
            <option value="None" selected>None</option>
<option value="m:">mobile</option>

Comment: Yes, I see your edits comply with the exception of a [mcve]. I have edited it to make it so (except for the minimal aspect),  as well as retracted my vote to close and adjusted my -1 vote. Also, HTML was missing the end tags: `</form>`, `</div>`, and `</section>`. Also, only `<input>`  has a `type` attribute, `<select>` do not. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: From a quick comparison between HTML an JS, it appears that they do not belong to each other. All or most of the DOM references do not exist. It is impossible that this code should work at all.  If you would have tried to use this and debugged with the console you'd immediately have known this (or even try to just run it normally)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I stripped out as much of the code as possible just to get down to the issue. so this has left some things hanging but the form fields that I need to run are running. Hope that makes sense. My hope was just for help on the drop down. If I can get that to fill the live preview then it's a success! I am not the greatest developer and this is far above my capabilities but hoping someone can guide me to solve that one thing. I appreciate that the code overall has some messy elements. It's a bit of a Frankenstein situation BUT it does run great other than that drop down

Comment: I've done a bit more messing around and I think I can solve this by adjusting the addEventListener for just the dropdown. it's currently "keyup" which does not seem to work for a dropdown.

Comment: I've given OP +1 for tenacity. Hopefully I'll have an answer soon.